# side nav bar height issue

Tags: html, css

Well i am developing a back-end system with a side navigation bar on the left side!

I am using Bulma CSS framework and developing with Laravel.

I been doing side navigation like this for as long as i can remember but for some reason i am having some weird height issues so:

**Note** This is not the whole code its just the wrapping div because the whole side navigation code is 140 lines of code.

Side Navigation html structure:

```css
#admin-side-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    left: 0;
    top: 3.5rem;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.1);
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="admin-side-menu">
    <aside class="menu">
    </aside>
<div>
```

Now my problem is that only if i have the browser window at full size i get the height to be all the way to the bottom, if the window is sized and i have to scroll down to see all the content the height of the navigation bar will not cover all the way at the bottom!

I tried height:100% and height: 100vh; but nothing is working!

Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting the height of body to 100vh, and if you use `top:3.5rem` then you should use `height:calc(100% - 3.5rem)` on the sidebar

Comment: the issue is not reproducible so how could we help you!

Answer (score 1):

You made a very silly mistake

Update the position property.

```
#admin-side-menu {
   position: fixed;
}
```

`position: absolute` will position it absolutely with respect to the nearest relative positioned element or else with relative to the browser window.

`position: fixed` will make the element fixed in a specific position even if you scroll.

Read more about position property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: I tried what u suggested before i posted and the navigation is scrolling with the rest of the content!
if for example the browser window is sized and i have to scroll to see the content the sidebar is scrolling up/down because it's fixed!
Only if the browser window is full screen i get the correct position!

Comment: Please put a live demo which I can inspect for the issue.

Comment: I created a basic layout with the issue here https://codepen.io/Acidust/full/japGXz/   Check it out

Comment: As soon as i add `posiiton: fixed` in the demo the sticky functionality is visible to me. Then what is the issue from your side?

Comment: with position fixed if u make the browser window small and scroll up/down the side bar moves up down and i dont like that

Comment: Just tested and I can't see the side bar scrolling can you add a small gif or video that is sowing the issue??

Answer (score 0):

try a `max-height: 300px` or how many pixels you want so it looks nice. You can also set that with JS depending on how many items you have.